# My Vector3 return function doesn't seem to use the right float variable value that's declared in my script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this card game with the following vector3 return method:

```
Vector3 GetCurrentPos()
{
    var _currentPos = new Vector3((_CardGameEngine._playerCardsInHand - 1) * (0 - _cardWidth / 2) + ((_cardWidth) * (_ownCardCount - 1)), -_camHeight + _cardHeight / 2, _cardLayer);
    _currentPos.x = _currentPos.x * 0.8f * _CardGameEngine._playerCardsOverflowRate;
    if ((_currentPos.x + (_cardWidth / 2)) > (_camWidth / 2.1))
    {
        _CardGameEngine._playerCardsOverflowAlert = true;
    }
    _currentPos.x = _currentPos.x - _edgeOffset;
    return _currentPos;
}
```

I'm pretty new to Unity I should mention by the way. Any, this basically keeps track of where the card should go back into the player's hand depending on how many other cards are in hand etc. Actually works flawlessly except for the very last part "_edgeOffset". This is a private float that eventually gets assigned the following value:

```
public float _edgeOffset;
_edgeOffset = (transform.position.x + (_boxCol.bounds.size.x / 2f)) - (_camWidth / 2f);
```

_edgeOffset gets called in Update() in certain scenarios when a card gets enlarged but part of it will enlarge past the screen. I'm essentially trying to keep the card on-screen as it gets enlarged by finding the offset. That "_edgeOffset" should subtract that amount from the GetCurrentPos() method I mentioned earlier, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it doesn't work!

If I print everything in the console, all of the values that calculate _edgeOffset are correct, and I can see that the value of _edgeOffset is correct as well. But if I print the value of GetCurrentPos() right after, it literally just doesn't subtract that from the x value.

I have no clue what's going on and am losing my mind haha... I was feeling pretty good about things but this is been such a sudden road-block and I have no idea what's going on. I could probably figure out a different way to achieve what I want, but I just want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Why are you doing so much? And using odd variables such as var instead of Vector3?

Why not just use transform.localPosition or transform.position to get the position?

Also, for your purposes, it will be better to save the card positions in a Vector3[] array then assign the cards to the first open position when putting into the hand.

Comment: From my understanding typing var in that function is equivalent to typing Vector3. Also, it's called CurrentPos, but I'm not trying to find the position of the card on the screen, it's calculating where the card should move towards in my hand (once you stop dragging it around for example). Also I'm relatively new to Unity so that's probably why I'm doing too much hahaha. The idea of a vector3 array for the hand makes a lot of sense though as well. I still want to understand, however, why this problem is happening.. if anyone knows haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

In the editor, drag cards into the places that I want them, then save their Vector3 positions found in the RectTransform as an array of Vector3[]

Then, OnMouseUp, I will activate a bool in my card which runs a transform.Translate in my card update function.

*This script is quickly tossed together and will need some editing but the general idea should work for your issue.*
I.E.

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isDragging;

    public Card clickedCard;

    //turn into an object if you wish
    public Vector3[] cardPositions;
    public bool[] hasCard;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            //run dragging code
        }

        //mouse released
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && clickedCard!=null)
        {
            clickedCard.ReturnCard(GetFirstOpenPos());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Requires:
    ///     <br/>cardPositions.Length = hasCard.Length
    ///     <br/>and
    ///     <br/>cardPositions and hasCard != null
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Vector3</returns>
    Vector3 GetFirstOpenPos()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < hasCard.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hasCard[i])
            {
                hasCard[i] = false;
                return cardPositions[i];
            }
        }

        throw new System.Exception("No available return positions! Fix in Editor");
    }
}

public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isReturning;
    float returnSpeed;
    Vector3 returnPos;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isReturning)
        {
            transform.Translate(returnPos * returnSpeed);

            if(Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, returnPos)) < 1)
            {
                transform.position = returnPos;
                isReturning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets this card to be sent to returnPos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="returnPos">The global position this card will go to</param>
    public void ReturnCard(Vector3 returnPos)
    {
        this.returnPos = returnPos;
        isReturning = true;
    }
}
```